# How replace auto-complete-mode with company-mode in all major mode using it?

Tags: hooks, major-mode, auto-complete-mode, minor-mode, aliases

How I can replace auto-complete-mode with company-mode in all major mode using it?

i.e. make all modes which activating auto-complete-mode (e.g. c-mode or sh-mode etc), activate company-mode instead (and don't activate auto-complete-mode).

Comment: c-mode and sh-mode don't activate auto-complete-mode, there must be something in your config doing that...

Comment: maybe my distribution it configured differently (i'm using Fedora)

Comment: emacs -q ~/.emacs turns on AC, but emacs -Q ~/.emacs doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall `emacs-auto-complete` using `yum` or `dnf` and install `company` using the emacs package manager. Turn company on with `(global-company-mode)` ur use `*mode-hook`s to turn it on for specific modes.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora supplies some system-wide init files which turns on AC mode on some major modes.
this will do what I asked in the question:

```
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(defun my_auto-complete-mode-hook_1 ()
                     (when auto-complete-mode (auto-complete-mode 0))
                     (company-mode 1))
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'my_auto-complete-mode-hook_1)
```